# Tensorflow memory leak in tf.decode_csv function

Tags: python-3.x, memory, tensorflow, memory-leaks

So I am running a DNN that is based upon the iris Model located here:https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator and the textlineReader advice located here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data

It is having a memory leak problem, and I have narrowed down the leak to these few lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def main():
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(file_path)
    defaults = [[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0]]
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    for i in range(50000):
      columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=defaults)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Where the .csv file referred to by file_path contains 1 line:

> 5.9,3.0,4.2,1.5,1

When I run the program this is my system usage over 60 seconds:
[image: System Usage]

Interestingly, all of the memory gets deallocated when I kill the program, or when the OOM manager does.

Anyway, I have to use batch processing in my program because of the size of the training dataset, so I have to perform the decoding of the .csv file in batches as well.

Is there a way to circumvent this leak, or is this a bug that should be reported?

Any information or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of obviously, the leak is coming from calling the decode_csv function, which is allocating some space that isn't deallocated until the program returns. The solution is to call the tf.decode_csv function outside of the for loop when getting a batch. As unintuitive as this sounds, I have been able to verify that it still shuffles the data with consecutive reads.

More importantly, this gives insight into the nature of what I believe are called graph operation in Tensorflow. One allocation no where near the session and it still works. I guess it is more like setting up a pipeline, and then feeding data through that pipelinne.

My code actually runs faster now too without all those mallocs!